# MS Dynamics CRM, adding tracking codes to links in email campaign

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

With MS Dynamics CRM 2012, is there a way of adding tracking codes to the end of each of the links within the email?

So we can identify which contacts clicked on the links to our website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box.

But CRM is xRM, so you can do this multiple ways.  Probably the easiest that comes to mind is to modify the email template to include the GUID of the recipient in the URL as a parameter.  Then inside your website (where the link directs to), log the visit based off of the GUID parameter.